# Android TimePicker not returning user set time but realtime, convert to long

Tags: android, datepicker, android-alertdialog, timepicker

I have a custom dialog with a datepicker and a time picker in it. The user sets the Date which all works fine. The date picker is the hidden and the time picker is shown. I am currently setting the time on the timepicker manually to 8 am.

I now want to convert the user set time in the time picker to a long which I am able to do however its showing me the current time on the phone in the logcat and not the actual set time... Thanks!

```
 button_continue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            if (timeset == false) {

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(datePickerDiet.getYear(), datePickerDiet.getMonth(), datePickerDiet.getDayOfMonth());
            long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
            System.out.println(startTime);

            // save to shared pref
            ProfilePrerences.getInstance().setLongValue(DietActivity.this, ProfilePrerences.KEY_START_DIET_DAY, startTime);


            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
            String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(startTime));
            System.out.println(dateString);

            datePickerDiet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            time_breakfast.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dialog_txt.setText("At what time do you have breakfast?");  
            time_breakfast.setCurrentHour(8);
            time_breakfast.setCurrentMinute(0);
            time_breakfast.clearFocus();
            timeset = true;

            }

            else if (timeset == true) {

        //  time_breakfast.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar2.set(time_breakfast.getCurrentHour(), time_breakfast.getCurrentMinute(), 0);


            long breakfasttime = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();
            System.out.println(breakfasttime);


            SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm"); 
            String dateString2 = formatter2.format(new Date(breakfasttime));
            System.out.println(dateString2);
            //  startdietdialog.cancel();
            ProfilePrerences.getInstance().setLongValue(DietActivity.this, ProfilePrerences.KEY_BREAKFAST_TIME, breakfasttime);
            timeset = false;

            }

        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is causing you the problem:

```
calendar2.set(time_breakfast.getCurrentHour(), time_breakfast.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
```

This is setting the year, month, day on calendar2 - not the hour, minute, second you intended.

Probably the easiest solution is call the direct methods - `setHour`, `setMinute`, etc., on calendar2.

Answer (score 0):

Two things: you're printing the current date (new Date):

```
String dateString2 = formatter2.format(new Date(breakfasttime));
System.out.println(dateString2);
```

You have to print calendar2 time:

```
String dateString2 = formatter2.format(calendar2.getTime());
System.out.println(dateString2);
```

The other is, Greg Ennis said, you're setting calendar2 time incorrectly: there is not such method to set only the hour, minutes and seconds. You should set year, month and day also or call set(Calendar.HOUR, h), set(Calendar.MINUTE, m), etc separately